# Heap Information in Windows 7

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, windows-7-x64

I made a simple experiment in win7 to test its organization of heaps in memory allocations, using the following code:

`char *pointer[50];`

`for(i=0;i<=49;i++) pointer[i]=new char[64];`

`for(i=0;i<=49;i++) printf("0x%X\n",pointer[i]);`

The output was:

`0x572F00`

`0x572F48`

`0x572F90`

......

Obviously, the space between two adjacent pointers has been 72 bytes rather than 64 bytes. There must be some information kept in the first few bytes of every heap chunk. I printed out the values in the 8 extra bytes and found them to be:

`71 39 19 36 B3 9F 00 08`

Can anyone please tell me how to tell the size of the heap chunk from these values? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just the idea you want to do this is pretty scary. This is undocumented information, liable to change without notice, liable to vary between debug and non-debug builds, etc, etc. I strongly suggest you find another way, such as storing the length using your own allocator.

In answer to your question, the information I know is stored is a forward and backward link and some flags. The links are probably stored in a single pointer using an XOR scheme. There is probably a sentinel as well.

If you really have to know the answer to this question, it's very easy to find. Simply compile and run your program in Visual Studio and step into the C run-time library code for `new`. All the declarations and code are there for you to read. Fully commented, very straightforward stuff.

Please note: this is **nothing** to do with the Windows 7 API. This is the runtime library associated with the C++ compiler (which I assume is Visual Studio).

There are several memory allocators internal to Windows 7, but that's an entirely different story.

Comment: Thanks. So no one has so far cracked the heap allocation mechanism in Windows7?

Comment: @RichardMorning: How did you get that idea? Your experiment deals only with the C++ runtime library, and that is well known. If you want to tackle the WinApi, it's a totally different story. See edit.

Comment: So how can I trigger the heap allocation of Windows7 API? By using `HeapAlloc()` directly?

Comment: @RichardMorning: Yes, `HeapAlloc()` can allocate on the default per-process heap, provided by `GetProcessHeap()`. It's well documented because it's the source of many vulnerabilities. If that's your interest there are far better sites than this one.